# vb.net I have two monitor and need to open forms on same monitor

Tags: vb.net, forms, detection, monitor

How do I open a second form on the same monitor even if the user moves the app form to another monitor when it is running?

In need to learn how to open the `FrmPopUp` on the same monitor as the `FrmMain` even if `FrmMain` has been moved during run time. Note: the `FrmPopUp` auto closes in 5 seconds.

Currently when I run my vb.net app on my second monitor it always opens on the main monitor not the second monitor.

Please, Help this is my first post and want to thank everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you make the show command, set the location of the windows, the same of the original form:

```
Dim Value as Point
Value = Me.Location;
Form2.Location = Value
```

Comment: You welcome, if that resolve your problem, please set as answer.